# Typescript noImplicitReturns rejects exhaustive if but accepts exhaustive switch

Tags: typescript

I'm running into an inconsistency with `noImplicitReturns` in Typescript 3.6.3.

This works just fine ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAQwFyIM5QE4xgDmiAPomCALYBGApngJSIDeAUIpzgO4xQQALRCigBPAA504wRGmbsuixBDTY6iAES4CxDRg5LDeOlBB4kARgDcBwyrWbKtBntuGux0+cQAmG4oBfNgCgA))

```
function f(a: string | number) {
    switch (typeof a) {
        case "string":
            return 1;
        case "number":
            return 2;
    }
}
```

However this one fails ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAQwFyIM5QE4xgDmiAPomCALYBGApngJSIDeAUIp4jMIilAE8ADnTi80iALyTEAIlwFis5uy5rEeOlBB4kARgDcHLgF9EdADbY63Xv2GjxUmbMq0Gy1sfUatOpABMRmombCZAA))

```
function f(a: string | number) {
    if (typeof a == "string") {
        return 1;
    } else if (typeof a == "number") {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Even though the two implementations are functionally identical, one errors with `TS7030 Not all code paths return a value`. Why does Typescript behave this way? And can I make the `if` implementation work?

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#17358](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17358)

Comment: @jcalz thanks, the `assertNever` util in that issue looks like it [solves](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoDkMBu2AFAB4BciYh2AlJdUVogN4BQiniUAFlnAHcqGIQFEs-LMQBEAVWqkADhmgYAJojgAjAFYqolaYgDUiUrQDcbAL5s2oSLASJgxZJVRQsMMAHNEAD5UIAC2WnSsHFwwwIjEUACeynCxyIgAvOmI0p7eftK0kVzFiFgYUCBYSACMVsXWiBgANpiIMXGJyakZWdJgoeFYBUUlnGUVVYgATHVcDc2t7KNj5ZVIaJg4+ExullGcttZAA) this, if you want to post as an answer